# Отфильтровать данные без разделителей в строке

Tags: php, парсер

Есть строка, с параметрами и рандомным количеством элементов. Например:

```
20% шерсть 30% хлопок 50% лен
```

а может быть и такой:

```
20% шерсть,80% хлопок
```

или такой:

```
40 % хлопок, 60 % шерсть
```

т.е. нет единого знака, который можно взять за разделитель, и нет постоянного количества элементов.

**Задача:**

Распарсить строку, получив данные в едином формате вида:

```
40% хлопок, 60% шерсть
```

(т.е. на выходе должно быть: знак процента после числа не должен отделяться пробелом, наименование после процента должно быть отделено пробелом и значения должны быть разделены запятой)

Не могу сообразить, как вообще можно в таких хаотично представленых данных провести фильтрацию..

Дробить строку по explode - нет единого разделителя. Регуляркой - возможно ли вообще написать логику для такого случая..

**UPD**

Забыл указать один из важных моментов, моя ошибка, но, может иметь место и такой вариант:

```
55% мериносовый хлопок 45% вискоза
```

т.е. наименование может состоять из двух слов и разделяться пробелом

**UPD2 Дополненный вариант принятого ответа**

Отличный пример от @Ипатьев, с выводом результата. Вырезает любые ненужные слова и разграничивает запятыми с пробелом:

```
$s = 'состав 20% шерсть 30% хлопок 50% лен';

$regexp = '~(\d+).*?%\W([\p{L}\s]*)~u';
preg_match_all($regexp, $s, $matches);
list(, $digits, $words) = $matches;
$result = [];
foreach ($digits as $i => $digit) {
    $result[] = "$digit% ".trim($words[$i]);
}

echo implode(', ', $result);
```

Выдает в итоге:

```
20% шерсть, 30% хлопок, 50% лен
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это хороший пример чтобы понять мощь регулярных выражений.
Для регулярок это совершенно примитивная задача, все делается одним довольно простым

```
$regexp = '~(\d+).*?%\W([\p{L}\s]*)~u';
preg_match_all($regexp, $s, $matches);
list(, $digits, $words) = $matches;
$result = [];
foreach ($digits as $i => $digit) {
    $result[] = "$digit% ".trim($words[$i]);
}
```

Comment: спасибо за пример, но, честно скажу, не совсем понял, как им воспользоваться, т.к. в регулярках еще очень слаб. Не могли бы вы немного дополнить с живым примером. Очень хочется понять данный вариант

Comment: @Amsterdam http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/98782189e718d03298de95f59ce778a3448a8ecf

Comment: @Verng не создает запятые в качестве разделителя между наименованиями, или я что то не так делаю

Comment: Но вариант мощный, как вижу. Удаляет любое ненужное слово, которое попадается в строку, оставляет только нужные значения. Еще бы подкорректировать ответ, что бы был проще для понимания так сказать дилетантам в регулярках, вроде меня

Comment: Вы получили массив `$result` и дальше можете делать с ним что хотите, сделайте `echo implode(', ', $result)` и будут вам запятые.

Comment: @Verng собственно, так уже и сделано, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Возможно не самое элегантное решение:

```
<?php
$str = '20% шерсть 30% хлопок 50% лен';
$str = str_replace(' ', '', $str);


$w = "/(\W+)/";
$str_number = array_diff( preg_split($w,$str), array('') );
$d = "/(\d+)\%/";
$str_name = array_diff( preg_split($d,$str), array('') );

$array = array_combine($str_number, $str_name);

$newstr = '';
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    //echo "<p>{$key}% {$value}</p>";
    $newstr .= "{$key}% {$value}, ";
}

echo trim($newstr, ', ');
```

[Здесь можно посмотреть](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/89f9b724df02254c151fbc8b7930fec82045f419)

[Вариант строкой](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/68d26d621348f4aaaf389370ed370222ff7e6763)

[Вариант три, заменим запятые и оставим длинные слова с пробелами](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b7728be9280f3bc308c59fc28ef4658b7580b50e)

Comment: спасибо за вариант! Но несколько не соответствует условию - не выставляет запятые в качестве разделителя между значениями

Comment: Так я просто выводил блоки, далее при работе с массивом, делайте все что угодно. Сейчас добавлю строку.

Comment: шикарно! Единственное, не решает вопрос, который я забыл указать изначально. Вариант с двумя словами в названии, например: "55% мериносовый хлопок 45% вискоза" - между словами стирает пробел.

Comment: Это тоже не проблема тримьте тогда после выполнения разбития строк, перед выводом и уберите вторую строку по замене пробелов

Comment: кажется, все работает как нужно. Восхитительно! Не думал, что возможно обойтись достаточно легким вариантом, в плане количества кода. Спасибо!!

Answer (score 1):

Сделал данные чуть грязнее.
Наверняка можно написать лучше, но в целом регулярка решает данную задачу.
остается убрать последнюю запятую в строке.

тестил здесь http://phptester.net/

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\s*%\s*?)/im', '% ', '20     % шерсть  30 %    хлопок,50% лен  ,20 % Вискоза 20 % лайкра');
$str = preg_replace('/(\d*%)(\s*)?([A-Za-zа-яА-Я]*)(\s{1,})?(,)?/imu', '$1 $3,', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/(\s*,\s*)/im', ', ', $str);
echo $str;
```

Обновленный вариант с учетом нескольких слов в названии состава

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\s*%\s*?)/im', '% ', '20     % шерсть  30 %    хлопок,50% лен  ,55% мериносовый хлопок 45% вискоза');
$str = preg_replace('/(\d*% [A-Za-zа-яА-Я ]*)(\d*%)/imu', '$1, $2', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/(\s*,\s*)/im', ', ', $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: Если по вашему примеру, то запятую можно таким способом убрать `echo trim($str, ', ');`

Comment: @Artem спасибо! Сейчас тестирую ваш вариант. Пока выглядит превосходно!

Comment: @Artem нашел вариант, при котором получается не то, что нужно (упустил изначально, нужно было указать в примере, моя ошибка), но если в наименовании идет два слова подряд, то они разделяются, например: "55% мериносовый хлопок 45% вискоза". В таком случае, название разбивается запятой..

Comment: @Amsterdam
Вот так возможно даже лучше будет)

`$str = preg_replace('/(\s*%\s*?)/im', '% ', '20     % шерсть  30 %    хлопок,50% лен  ,55% мериносовый хлопок 45% вискоза');
$str = preg_replace('/(\d*% [A-Za-zа-яА-Я ]*)(\d*%)/imu', '$1, $2', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/(\s*,\s*)/im', ', ', $str);
echo $str;`

Comment: @Atrem к сожалению обновленный вариант не совсем корректно справляется с проставлением запятых. Например: "20% шерсть 30% хлопок 50% лен 55% мериносовый хлопок 45% вискоза" , выставляет запятую только после шерсти и льна..